# Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) running Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

The description gives me a pretty clear idea, what the error depends on. But I am not sure how to fix it. Do I have to pay for Heroku or can the issue be solved on the free version.

The script is very simple.
I am collecting a lot of 3rd party API's, into one collected feed with pagination added.

So like this

```
const api = [];
Promise.all(
  endpoints.map((endpoint) =>
      fetch(endpoint)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(e => {
        // .... something
        return e;
      })
      catch(err => console.log(err)
).then(result => api.push(result)

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  let { size, page } = req.query;
  page = page * 20;
  size = page + 20;
  res.json(api.slice(page, size))
})
```

When the server is up and running local, it is working fine everytime.
When I deploy it to Heroku, I get the Error R14 most of the times. Not all the times! If I refresh the page 4-6 times, it will receive the data.

Comment: what is the size of the data you're loading? Your laptop specs most likely far exceed the specs of the heroku box it runs on

Comment: Well, it ends up with an array of 20.000 objects. I can't tell the size exactly, is there a way that can show me that?

Comment: Try `const used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
console.log(\`The script uses approximately ${used} MB\`);` h/t https://www.valentinog.com/blog/node-usage/

Comment: Thanks! It tells me it is using 529.9 MB

Comment: As far as I can tell, you get up to 512 MB for free, which explains the issue. Thanks for the answer to my issue @holtc